# Adding a Cell value into the HTML body of an Email in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have to order reports on accounts daily and then send an email with all of the reports but it has to be formatted a certain way.  I finally made an Excel macro to order the reports but I am trying to make the macro also email the reports.  Here is what I have so far.

```
Sub Email()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Email As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    K = 2
    Do While ws.Cells(K, 1) <> ""
        ws.Cells(K, 5) = "ACCT:" & ws.Cells(K, 1).Value

        K = K + 1
    Loop

    Email = "Hello, <br><br>" & _
                    "The following reports were ordered today: <br><br>" & _
                            "<br> ws.Cells(2, 5) & _
                            '"<br> ACCT:" & ws.cells(1, 2) & _
                             "<br><br> Thank you." & _
                       "<br><br><br> <i> Please note Call if you have any questions </i>" & _

    With OutMail
        .to = "me@me.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Statements Ordered"
        .HTMLBody = Email                                
        .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

What I have it do is take the AC numbers that are in the book in column A and then match it with ACCT: so that cells E:E900 have ACCT: 12345.... but I dont know how to add that cell into the HTML body.  Below it I have commented out a 2nd way I tried but also failed and that was to try and match the ACCT: & ws.Cells(1,2).

So Question: is there a way to either use an If then statement inside of the HTMLbody or is there a way to add the cell value inside the HTMLbody?

Comment: Change "<br> ws.Cells(2, 5) & _ to "<br>" & ws.Cells(2, 5).Value & _

Comment: ...and remove the extra `& _` from the end of that string

Comment: bingo! thanks so much just realized I need more help but ill post a 2nd question for that if one of you guys makes an answer ill accept it.  Thanks again I must have been staring at it to long.